# NTLM Authentication using Flutter / dart

Tags: dart, flutter

Backstory, I am trying to connect to a website that uses NTLM Authentication. I've been facing a lot of issues already concerning that but I am persistent and I want to succeed.

I am using Flutter and I tried searching for any http client in dart that supports NTLM / NTLM/2 authentication and I can't find anything. Is there a way to implement/ connect to a website using NTLM that works in flutter?

Comment: If there are already packages for native Android and iOS, you can easily connect them with your Flutter code. That would be a fast workaround if you would otherwise have to write a full plugin.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I am already following this approach however I am looking for something that works fully in dart/flutter since I want to prevent as much duplication as possible.

Comment: @KarimElGhandour it seems there's a lot of people interested! why don't you make your NTLM plugin open source? these people would probably help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably a bit late for this question specifically, but if anyone stumbles upon this like I did when searching for a solution, I've just released https://github.com/mrbbot/ntlm.

It's not tested extensively but it seems to be working for me.

---

### Installing

Add the dependency to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  ntlm: ^2.0.1
```

### Example Usage

```dart
import 'package:ntlm/ntlm.dart';

main() {
  var client = NTLMClient(
    domain: "",
    workstation: "LAPTOP",
    username: "User208",
    password: "password",
  );

  client.get(Uri.parse("https://example.com/")).then((res) {
    print(res.body);
  });
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Comment: I've just added a few more details, including an example.