# Flutter - HTTP response windows authentication

Tags: php, android, flutter, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I'm new in flutter.

I created an application that parse .JSON format from .php body using `http.get()`/`http.post()`.

everything is working normally when using the local database and local Apache server on my laptop.

the problem stared when I applied this project using windows server(domain) as database server and apache server, my flutter apps does't working anymore.

When I tried to access the .php file (checkConnection.php) using my browser on my laptop/android phone it is showing a popup that asking an windows authentication.

[Windows Auth Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06HKK.png)

checkConnection.php was working when i input my domain account.

**THE QUESTION.**

Does anyone know an alternative way to solve this issue?
maybe something like saving my credentials on the code?

This is the code that I used on my flutter application:

```
final response =
    await http.post("http://172.28.16.84/mobileglpi/login.php", body: {

  'username': txt_username.text,
  'password': txt_password.text,
});
var datauser = json.decode(response.body);
```

Comment: could anyone help me please :(

Comment: The Dart http client can't do NTLM - see [NTLM Authentication using Flutter / dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657927/ntlm-authentication-using-flutter-dart) You should turn off the requirement for authentication at IIS.

Comment: ooh i see, thanks for the explanation